# How to provisioning a SPFx web part using CSOM OnPrem (SP2016)

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, spfx-webparts, provisioning

I have developed a SPFx web part.
How do I provision the webpart part using **CSOM** to an OnPrem SharePoint 2016 server?

Answer (score 1):

**First,** [Set up your SharePoint client-side web part development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

- Install developer tools

  - Install NodeJS version 6.x.
- Install a code editor. You can use any code editor or IDE that supports client-side development to build your web part, such as:+

  - Visual Studio Code
  - Atom
  - Webstorm
- Install Yeoman and gulp
- Install Yeoman SharePoint generator

**Second,** [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).

**Third,** [Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint).

**Finally,** [Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page).

---

**Check Also**

- [SharePoint framework for SharePoint server 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. I have already created the spfx web part package. I want to know how to upload the package and add the app to site page using CSOM.

Comment: @Rune check the final step in the above answer.

Comment: @M.Qassa. There is no code displaying the provisioning at all. Have you really tried to do this yourself?

Comment: The method I used successfully: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1224160/Deploy-an-SpFX-sppkg-file-add-in-via-CSOM-to-on-pr